# How prove this $\sqrt{x^4+7x^3+x^2+7x}+3\sqrt{3x}+x^2-10x\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

let $x\ge 0$,show that
$$\sqrt{x^4+7x^3+x^2+7x}+3\sqrt{3x}+x^2-10x\ge 0$$

My try: 
let
$a=\sqrt{x^4+7x^3+x^2+7x},b=3\sqrt{3x}+x^2-10x$
so
$$\Longleftrightarrow a+b\ge 0$$
if $b\ge 0$ then $a+b\ge 0$ is Obviously

so we only prove  this case $b\le 0$.

so I think this inequality have nice methods.Thank you

Comment: The equivalence is wrong. Actually $3\sqrt{3x}+x^2-10x\geqslant0$ "most of the time", which guarantees the first inequality.

Comment: Oh,sorry,I have know

Comment: [Special value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt%28x^4%2B7x^3%2Bx^2%2B7x%29%2Bx^2-10x%2B3\sqrt%283x%29+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D3&dataset=&equal=Submit) at $x=\frac43$.

Comment: ((Since the question was heavily redacted, some comments/answers do not apply anymore.))

Comment: "so I think this inequality have nice methods" How do you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem with very careful application of squaring.

$\sqrt{x^4+7x^3+x^2+7x}+3\sqrt{3x}\ge 10x - x^2$

Since this is true for $x > 10$ (positive greater than negative), the proof can continue under the assumption that $x < 10$.

Under this assumption, both sides are positive so squaring produces an equivalently true formula:

$$2\cdot {3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\,\sqrt{x}\,\sqrt{{x}^{4}+7\,{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+7\,x}+{x}^{4}+7\,{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+34\,x \ge {x}^{4}-20\,{x}^{3}+100\,{x}^{2}$$

$$\frac{2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\,\sqrt{{x}^{4}+7\,{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+7\,x}}{\sqrt{x}}  \ge -27\,{x}^{2}+99\,x-34$$

Now we have 2 cases, one where the right hand side is positive, and one where it is negative.

Case 1 : $0 < x < -\frac{\sqrt{681}-33}{18}$ or $\frac{\sqrt{681}+33}{18} < x < 10$, RHS is negative, so the relation holds.

Case 2: $-\frac{\sqrt{681}-33}{18} < x < \frac{\sqrt{681}+33}{18}$, RHS is positive:

$$\left(\frac{2\,{3}^{\frac{3}{2}}\,\sqrt{{x}^{4}+7\,{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+7\,x}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2  \ge \left(-27\,{x}^{2}+99\,x-34\right)^2$$

$$-729\,{x}^{4}+5454\,{x}^{3}-10881\,{x}^{2}+6840\,x-400 \ge 0$$

$$-{\left( 3\,x-4\right) }^{2}\,\left( 81\,{x}^{2}-390\,x+25\right) \ge 0$$

Only 1 root exists in this range, $x = \frac 4 3$ as Did pointed out in his comment.  The other two roots are in the range of case 1.  Picking any $x_0$ and $x_1$ for $-\frac{\sqrt{681}-33}{18} < x_0 < \frac 4 3$ and $\frac 4 3 < x_1 < \frac{\sqrt{681}+33}{18}$ shows the polynomial to be positive on both sides of the root.

Comment: Nicely done. +1.

Answer (score 2):

in case $10x-x^2-3\sqrt{3x} \ge0 \iff 0.534922<\sqrt{x}\le2.8607,\Longleftrightarrow (x^4+7x^3+x^2+7x)- (x^2-10x+3\sqrt{3x})^2=27x^3-2*3^{3/2}x^{5/2}-99x^2+20*3^{3/2}x^{(3/2)}-20*x=t^2(27t^4-2*3^{3/2}t^3-99t^2+20*3^{3/2}t-20), t=\sqrt{x}$

$27t^4-2*3^{3/2}t^3-99t^2+20*3^{3/2}t-20=27(t+\dfrac{(+5 \sqrt{3}+2 \sqrt{30})}{9})(t-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}})^2(t-\dfrac{(2 \sqrt{10}-5)}{3 \sqrt{3}}) \ge0$

when $x=\dfrac{4}{3}$ get "="

Comment: Thank you, But for my problem is true

Comment: This doesn't disprove the original assertion. What is wrong is the equivalence claimed by the OP to his squared-up version.

Comment: I know this is $\Longleftrightarrow $   not true

Comment: I have edit,Thank you